# Typescript - Combine two arrays of objects by field value

Tags: typescript

I have two different arrays of objects and need them to be combined by specific value of field.

```
array1 =
[
  { id: "id7", dateCreated: "2017-01-24", client: "Clipper"}, 
  { id: "id2", dateCreated: "2017-01-22", client: "Sniper" },
  { id: "id3", dateCreated: "2017-02-22", client: "Beeper" }
  { id: "id1", dateCreated: "2017-01-29", client: "Reaper" }
]

array2 =
[
  { id: "id2", dateExpired: "2020-01-24"}, 
  { id: "id1", dateExpired: "2020-01-22"}
]
```

I am expecting to get something like that in the end:

```
newData =
[
  { id: "id7", dateCreated: "2017-01-24", client: "Clipper"}, 
  { id: "id2", dateCreated: "2017-01-22", client: "Sniper", dateExpired: "2020-01-24" },
  { id: "id3", dateCreated: "2017-02-22", client: "Beeper" }
  { id: "id1", dateCreated: "2017-01-29", client: "Reaper", dateExpired: "2020-01-22" }
]
```

There are lots of fields in each and they are not sorted so I have to find the proper array2 object first and then combine them.

I have tried the following and unfortunately for some reason it either not reach the *if statement* or don't push new lines to newData.

```
let newData = [];
array1.forEach((item, row) => {
   let find = array2.find((element) => {
     return item.id===element.id
   });

   if (find) newData.push(Object.assign({},item,find));

});
```

Comment: `return item.id=element.id` The equality operators in JavaScript/TypeScript are `==` and `===`. `=` is the assignment operator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main issue with your original code is that you were using [`=`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Assignment) (the assignment operator) instead of [`==`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators) or [`===`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators) (comparison operators). But you can simplify your code even more using [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/User:wbamberg/Examples_on_top/Array.prototype.map():v2) and some es6 syntax:

```js
const array1 =
[
  { id: "id7", dateCreated: "2017-01-24", client: "Clipper"}, 
  { id: "id2", dateCreated: "2017-01-22", client: "Sniper" },
  { id: "id3", dateCreated: "2017-02-22", client: "Beeper" },
  { id: "id1", dateCreated: "2017-01-29", client: "Reaper" },
];
const array2 =
[
  { id: "id2", dateExpired: "2020-01-24"}, 
  { id: "id1", dateExpired: "2020-01-22"},
];
const newData = array1.map((item, row) => {
   const found = array2.find((element) => item.id == element.id);
   return { ...item, ...found };
});
console.log(newData);
```

Comment: The `(found || {})` is unnecessary. The object spread syntax can be applied to `undefined` directly.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Thanks for pointing that out. I think I knew that at some point but I had forgotten.

Answer (score 1):

Three problems:

- You are trying to use `=` to compare the IDs instead of `==` or `===`.
- The variable for your array is named `newData`, but you are trying to push to a variable named `newArray`.
- You are conditionally pushing to the array, when you should instead *always* push to the new array and conditionally merge in the found object if there is one.

After fixing these, and the missing comma in `array1`, it produces the described result:

```js
let array1 = [{
    id: "id7",
    dateCreated: "2017-01-24",
    client: "Clipper"
  },
  {
    id: "id2",
    dateCreated: "2017-01-22",
    client: "Sniper"
  },
  {
    id: "id3",
    dateCreated: "2017-02-22",
    client: "Beeper"
  }, {
    id: "id1",
    dateCreated: "2017-01-29",
    client: "Reaper"
  }
]

let array2 = [{
    id: "id2",
    dateExpired: "2020-01-24"
  },
  {
    id: "id1",
    dateExpired: "2020-01-22"
  }
]

let newData = [];
array1.forEach((item, row) => {
  let find = array2.find((element) => {
    return item.id === element.id
  });

  newData.push(Object.assign({}, item, find || {}));
});

console.log(newData);
```

Comment: Thank you. First two items just typo on rewriting the code manually.

For some reason it returns it as

newData =
[
  { id: "id7", dateCreated: "2017-01-24", client: "Clipper", dateExpired: "2020-01-22"}, 
  { id: "id2", dateCreated: "2017-01-22", client: "Sniper",  dateExpired: "2020-01-22" },
  { id: "id3", dateCreated: "2017-02-22", client: "Beeper", dateExpired: "2020-01-22" }
  { id: "id1", dateCreated: "2017-01-29", client: "Reaper", dateExpired: "2020-01-22" }
]
just adding the data from array2 to each in array1

Comment: @Nick Sounds like you still have the `=` problem. Did you actually fix that in your code?

Comment: Definitely, had to rewrite it manually. So it was the reason of typo here. None of such issues in my code. Still, lot of thanks for your sharp eye and help)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `array2` entries all have unique IDs, you can preprocess it into an object that behaves like a lookup table to get a faster lookup by `id` before applying [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to `array1`:

```js
const array1 = [
  { id: "id7", dateCreated: "2017-01-24", client: "Clipper" }, 
  { id: "id2", dateCreated: "2017-01-22", client: "Sniper" },
  { id: "id3", dateCreated: "2017-02-22", client: "Beeper" },
  { id: "id1", dateCreated: "2017-01-29", client: "Reaper" }
]

const array2 = [
  { id: "id2", dateExpired: "2020-01-24" }, 
  { id: "id1", dateExpired: "2020-01-22" }
]

const results = array1.map(
  function (value) {
    return { ...value, ...this[value.id] }
  },
  array2.reduce(
    (lut, value) => Object.assign(lut, { [value.id]: value }),
    {}
  )
)

console.log(results)
```